# Let $X=\{x|x=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n}, n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. Find $X \cap \mathbb{N}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, integers

I am out of hints here. Its trivial to show $1$ is a solution. How to show it's the only solution?

Can someone please give me some hints?

*Please do not use congruence, limits or derivatives because they are out of scope of the chapter which has this question.*

Answer (score -1):

[The harmonic number is never an integer for $n>1$. In fact (as shown in the article), the largest power of $2$ dividing the denominator in the simplest form, is the largest power of $2$ not exceeding $n$](https://www.dropbox.com/s/auxzc1w0mubpx55/Harmonic_Number_Non_Integer.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: Much better to write a self-contained answer here.

Comment: @SimonS not true, but still, this should rather be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @SimonS You can access the link without dropbox account.

Comment: @Simon No, you dont need to have an account. just close the box which asks for login details.

Comment: (Yes, ok. The first time I tried to access the link it asked for an account. But now it does not.)